# Fuzzy/non-deterministic behaviour for a simple Bash script

Tags: bash

```
[root@localhost ~]# time cpumode 
Driver:   acpi-cpufreq
Boost:    disabled
Governor: ondemand
Average and maximum frequencies now: 2159MHz 2929MHz
Maximum allowed frequency is 3800MHz (out of 4928MHz)

real    0m0.214s
user    0m0.017s
sys 0m0.011s
[root@localhost ~]# time cpumode 
Driver:   acpi-cpufreq
Boost:    disabled
Governor: ondemand
Average and maximum frequencies now: 2431MHz 2738MHz
Maximum allowed frequency is 3800MHz (out of 4928MHz)

real    0m0.024s
user    0m0.018s
sys 0m0.013s
```

There's almost an order of magnitude difference in the amount of time the script takes to run, and it happens randomly.

No idea how it's possible. When enabling debugging (uncommenting the first two lines), the [script](https://github.com/birdie-github/useful-scripts/blob/master/cpumode) always executes in around 0.134 seconds.

If this is not reproducible on your PC/laptop, don't bother. Just a weird observation I've not seen ever in my entire life and which I cannot explain. I can run it via `strace -f -t` but it's not something I'm willing to do right now ;-)

---

With Linux 5.19.4 I can no longer reproduce this behavior.

Comment: What is the actual issue? That the script takes slightly different times?

Comment: Slightly? ;-) 0.02ms vs 0.2ms - that's almost an order of magnitude difference.

Comment: Sigh. I really need to be sure to finish at least two cups of coffee before commenting. Sorry, I just compared the `214s` to `24s` conveniently ignoring the 0. Does this happen often? Can't it simply be that something else was running on the machine that was taking up resources and that slowed the script down?

Comment: This could have been possible if I ran low on RAM and the Linux kernel evicted all the related binaries from the disk cache, so it needed to read the actual files/libraries again, however I have something like 60GB of RAM totally free, so all the runs are from RAM. Also the system is near completely idle at all times, so no background/foreground tasks which could affect it either. The last idea is that maybe the CPU frequency subsystem is to blame but AFAIK the `ondemand` governor changes frequencies as fast as 10 000 times per second, so it shouldn't affect it either. In short this is crazy.

Comment: I really need to `strace` it but I'm not sure it'll work because strace adds a layer of complexity (as e.g. `set -x` and `PS4=` do), so the net result will be the same under strace. Weirdly long runs, e.g. over 0.2ms are longer, than `set -x/PS4=` runs. Maybe indeed it's frequency scaling at work - but it should be deterministic, yet it's not.

Comment: This is reproducible on my six-year old laptop with a mobile Intel CPU as well, LOL (I have Ryzen 7 5800X on my desktop). `0m0.145s` vs `0m0.051s` - the difference is not as pronounced but it's huge. Could be a kernel bug for all I know.

Comment: Do we talk about virtual machine? Have you check the actual load of the machine during two runs?

Comment: A physical PC and physical laptop, both nearly completely idle with a ton of free RAM. Fedora 36, kernel 5.18. My laptop's free shows ~10GB of free RAM, SWAP is disabled everywhere.

Comment: Isn't this just about the definition of 'real'?  Your `user` and `sys` times are comparable.  I imagine `real` just includes the amount of time your kernel is putting the task aside while it does other, higher priority things.  It may just be a measure of how busy your machine is at that moment.

Comment: ???? I can see this script instantly finishing (`0.024ms`) and taking time to finish (`0.214ms`). Is there no one here running Linux at all? Didn't expect people not trying to run the script on their PCs. It's safe to run. It's very simple code, doesn't touch anything outside of `/sys`. I can reproduce it on two completely different x86-64 devices, with drastically different HW configurations (other than being x86-64 compartible).

Answer (score 0):

I get similar differences, and it seems to be related to how processes are scheduled across CPUs.

On “slow” runs, I get output like

```
./cpumode > /dev/null  0.03s user 0.01s system 19% cpu 0.189 total
```

or

```
0.03user 0.01system 0:00.20elapsed 21%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 4004maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+5720minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

(respectively using `zsh`’s `time`, and GNU `time`; redirecting to `> /dev/null` both because I don’t care about the output and to eliminate terminal delays if they’re a factor).

On fast runs, I get

```
./cpumode > /dev/null  0.03s user 0.02s system 125% cpu 0.035 total
```

or

```
0.03user 0.01system 0:00.03elapsed 125%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 4092maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+5668minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

Notice the difference in CPU allocation.

Comment: But why? :-) ... The whole script is executed sequentially :-)

Comment: There are quite a lot of external processes involved, some of them involving pipes, so it’s not 100% sequential.

Comment: Even without actual parallel execution (setting the affinity), because there are so many processes involved the overall execution is subject to a fair amount of scheduling variation.

Comment: Funny though long and short runs are very similar in the amount of time they take.